# How to extract n rows based on similar column values in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe that has imported data from multiple csv files. The dataframe has a column that lists the filename each data point came from. From this large dataframe, I'd like to extract every 50 rows of data from the same filename. So from filename 1, extract rows 1,50,100, 150,etc and from filename 2 extract rows 1,50,100,150, and then combine all of the extracted rows into 1 dataframe with their filenames.

The problem is that all of the data is already imported into 1 dataframe. So using this 1 dataframe, how do I make a new one as explained above?

Another way to ask this question is:

I have a list of dataframes and I'd like to extract every 50 rows from each dataframe in the list and combine them into a new dataframe.

I know for a single dataframe I can do this:
new.df <- df1[seq(1,nrow(df1),50),]

How do I do this for each dataframe in a list and then combine those results into 1 large dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Deleted my answer as I'd made a fundamental mistake. `df1[seq(1,nrow(df1),50),]` will not give you rows "1, 50, 100, 150, etc." as pointed out by @Pierre Lafortune

Answer (score 0):

```
split_df <- split(df, df$filename)
subset_df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split_df, function(x) {x[c("your_rows_here"),]}))
```

Hope this solves it!